# Global routing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to apply a global route in CakePHP?

So for example:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/:token', 
        array('controller'=>'App'),
        array(
            'pass' => array('token')
            )
    );
```

The idea is that, if a NAMED parameter called token is passed to any URL that is handled by the App Controller (which should be everything) it will deal with it like:

`/users/login/123abc` where 123abc is the token.

And example of how I have done this with paging for my Notes controller:

```
Router::connect('/notes',
        array('controller'=>'notes','action'=>'index', 'page' => 1),
        array(
            'pass' => array('page')
        )
    );

    Router::connect('/notes/page/:page', 
        array('controller' => 'notes', 'action' => 'index'),
        array(
            'pass' => array('page'),
            'page' => '[1-9]+'
            )
    );
```

Which makes URLs like:

`/notes/page:1` become `/notes/page/1`

**The issue is that I am having to do this for each action and controller, and want to make it global so it applies to all controllers and actions. Hence my experiment with the app controller as a route parameter.**

Comment: Should we assume you tried that, but it didn't work?  Did it give you an error...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Define a route for all controllers

You can make the controller a variable in your route definition:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/page/:page', 
    array('controller' => 'action' => 'index'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('page'),
        'page' => '[1-9]+'
    )
);
```

In this way, there is only one route per action. Note that this route won't match any pagination url where there is a different order, limit or direction - Generally speaking Routes and pagination are difficult/fragile.

### Use Get parameters

The edited question mentions pagination arguments - if the main or only use case is pagination, you're better off using [get arguments](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters).

```
public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

i.e.

```
current/url
current/url?page=2
```

Since get arguments don't interfere with routing you can then forget about them in route definitions and there's no risk of the url changing significantly as a user navigates using pagination links. Future versions of cake are likely to remove named parameters and make get arguments the default for pagination.

Comment: Yeah I know it will work. But I want to change the URL so that it no longer has the `token:` prefix. If I did the above code for each controller, it would work as I want, but wondered if I could apply it globally without having to do it for each.

Comment: Make the URL become `/users/delete/123abc` instead of `/users/delete/token:123abc` which is what the above route would do normally if applied directly to a method, but I want to do it globally if possible.

Comment: **It doesn't handle the URL like that by default.** Named parameters in Cake are handled by the router like: `/page:1`. You have to create your own route to tailor it to look differently. I'll post an example in my OP of how I handle paging. I'm trying to get tokens to work in the same way, but do it globally instead of for each controller individually.

Comment: Just to confirm! I'm **NOT** trying to get the token value and use it, as it seems your example is demonstrating. I'm simply just altering the way the URL looks so it no longer has the parameter key in the URL.